# How do I get my regular expression to work with three specific numbers that are separated by hyphens?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to get this regular expression to work when I have 3 specific numbers that are separated by hyphens. The regex work when there are no hyphens.Can anyone tell me what I can do to solve this issue. I tried a combinations of \d+-, but nothing I tried worked. Thank you.

The number in this example is 012. I am trying to get the regex to match all combinations of 0-1-2.

import re

fname = ('regextest.txt')

fh = open(fname)

RegEx012 = re.compile(r'\b(?=[1-9]*0)(?=[02-9]*1)(?=[013-9]*2)\d+\b')

for i in fh:

```
if RegEx012.findall(i):

    print(i)
```

Data in file:

0-1-2

0-1-4

0-2-1

0-4-1

1-0-2

1-0-4

1-2-0

1-4-0

2-0-1

2-1-0

4-0-1

4-0-2

4-1-0

Desire results:

```
0-1-2
0-2-1
1-0-2
1-2-0
2-0-1
2-1-0
```

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the requirements? Are all numbers supposed to be of length 3? What are valid numbers? Also, can you include what program you working in?

Comment: I am using this regex in python. There is a total of three digits which should match only the below six numbers. 0-1-2
0-2-1
1-0-2
1-2-0
2-0-1
2-1-0

Comment: This is still not very clear. What are the actual allowed values. Only those you have shown, e.g.: `123` is not allowed?

Comment: Correct. When I use a for loop in python I only want to match the listed values and nothing else. There will be other three digit regex that I use, but when I have the solution for this one I can apply the changes to remaining ones. but the issue is the same, I am unable to filter out the 6 variations of any 3 digit number when there is hyphens in the number.  Thank you.

Comment: All this is information you should include in your post instead of keeping these in comments.

Comment: Please tell me if my understanding of the question, as set out in my answer, is correct. If it is, and you find it clear, feel free to borrow it (changed as you like, of course) to clarify your question.

Comment: Must the regex exclude `1-2-2`, or is that input never going to be in the file? For your *current input as shown*, your suggested regex is too inclusive; all that's needed is `[012]-[012]-[012]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that, for a given string, we are to match each substring of size 5 that is a permutation of the characters in the string `'012'`, with one hyphen between the first and second digits and another between the second and third digits.

For example, for the string:

```
There are 2-1-0 reasons to buy 1-2-0 dogs, but only 1-2-1 to buy 0-2-1 cats
```

`2-1-0`, `1-2-0` and `0-2-1` (but not `1-2-1`) would be matched.

That can be done with the following regular expression:

```
r'\b(([012])-(?!\2)([012])-(?!\2|\3)[012])\b'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHXcpz/4/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](http://tpcg.io/YNTySt1g)

```
\b            : assert word boundary
(             : begin capture group 1
  ([012])     : match one char in class in capture group 2
  -           : match '-'
  (?!\2)      : negative lookahead asserts next char does not
                equal the contents of capture group 
  ([012])     : match one char in class in capture group 3
  -           : match '-'
  (?!\2|\3)   : negative lookahead asserts next char does not
                equal the contents of capture group 2 or 3
  [012]       : match one char in class
)             : end capture group 1
\b            : assert word boundary
```

Capture group 1, which captures the match, is needed for `re.findall` as there are other capture groups.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect. I forgot to add that I am looking to do the same for specific digits and a wild card. Any number containing 0 and a 1.  Example: 01.  results 0-1-0,1-0-2, 2-0-1, 1-0-3, etc.

Comment: You could require a `0` and a `1` (and one more digit) with two positive lookaheads: `\b(?=[\d-]*0) (?=[\d-]*1)\d-\d-\d\b`.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I ran into another issue. When the two numbers are the same the regex does not work. Such as 00. It works with 01.